# Group lists of lists with multiple criteria in python

Tags: python, list

I want to group a list of lists into lists of lists according to multiple criteria:

1. Index 0 to 2 of each list must be identical
2. Index 3 of each list is within a plus or minus 5 catchment window of the fourth element.

If both conditions are true, group the lists into a list of lists. If not, don't group the lists.

I only managed to group lists into a list of lists if the first condition is true with a list comprehension using `operator.itemgetter`.

Here is an example of the code complying with the first condition:

```
 input_list = [[0, 0, 'increase', 3, 6, 3],
 [0, 0, 'increase', 10, 6, -4],
 [0, 0, 'increase', 11, 6, -5],
 [0, 0, 'increase', 20, 6, -1],
 [0, 1, 'increase', 3, 7, 4],
 [0, 2, 'low', 6, 2, -4]]

from operator import itemgetter
groupby_list = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(input_list,itemgetter(0,1,2))]
```

With the current code, the first four lists are group together, though the last one should not be group with the first three list as its index 3 (i.e. 20) is not within a plus or minus 5 catchment window of its fourth element (i.e. 6) (i.e. `6 not in [20-5 : 20+5 ]`).

Here is the desired output complying with both condition 1 and 2:

```
desired_output = [[[0, 0, 'increase', 3, 6, 3],
  [0, 0, 'increase', 10, 6, -4],
  [0, 0, 'increase', 11, 6, -5]],
 [[0, 0, 'increase', 20, 6, -1]],
 [[0, 1, 'increase', 3, 7, 4]],
 [[0, 2, 'low', 6, 2, -4]]]
```

How can I include the second condition in the current code or with an alternative method ?

Comment: You're using `groupby`, which requires that the input be sorted on the grouping key. Is that something you can rely on, or just a coincidence of your test data?

Comment: It is just a coincidence of the test data, thanks for highlighting that.

Comment: And do you want it to join together data that shares the same `[0:2]` slice but is otherwise out of sequence? Eg on `[[0, 0, 'increase'], [0, 1, 'low'], [0, 0, 'increase'], [0, 1, 'low']]` would you expect two groups or four?

Comment: I would expect 2 group e.g.  ````[[[0, 0, 'increase'], [0, 0, 'increase']], [[0, 1, 'low'],[0, 1, 'low']]] ````

Comment: Actually, I can even have the input sorted if it can simplify the code.

Comment: If you do that _and_ can accept output that didn't maintain order - say, all the grouped values together and then all the non-grouped values - it gets significantly simpler.

Comment: I would find with that solution I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the clarification that the data is not sorted - this is beyond the complexity I personally would try to handle with a comprehension or `itertools` recipes. Instead, I'd loop through and use a dict to map the grouping key to a list to append to. Something like this:

```
def groupable(row, catchment=5):
    return abs(row[4] - row[3]) <= catchment

def grouping_key(row):
    return row[0:2]

collectors = {}
result = []
for row in input_list:
    if groupable(row):
        key = grouping_key(row)
        if not key in collectors:
            # You could use a defaultdict or the setdefault method to shorten this a little
            # But you do still need to explicitly check whether or not you have a new collector and therefore need to append
            new_collector = []
            result.append(new_collector)
            collectors[key] = new_collector
        collectors[key].append(row)
    else:
        result.append([row])
```

That's stable over the initial order encountered, except that it groups later elements back into a list with earlier values that share their grouping key.

This is significantly simpler if you can accept output that doesn't maintain initial order - in particular, separating out the ungroupable values makes a difference. In that case, you can partition the list on the groupable predicate and then use `groupby` after all on the ones that are groupable (sorting the groupable partition first if it's not already).

The [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipes have a partition example:

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
```

So using that and the convenience functions I declared above (not required, you can use lambdas - or `itemgetter` as you observed initially in place of by `grouping_key`. Something like this:

```
groupable_rows, ungroupable_rows = partition(groupable, input_list)
return [list(g) for _,g in groupby(groupable_rows, grouping_key)] + [[row] for row in ungroupable_rows]
```

That's untested, but I hope the idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the input with key as `itemgetter(0,1,2)` along with `x[3]<=x[4]+5 and x[3]>=x[4]-5`

```
>>> f1 = itemgetter(0,1,2)
>>> f2 = lambda x: (f1(x), x[3]<=x[4]+5 and x[3]>=x[4]-5)
>>> groupby_list = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(input_list, key=f2), f2)]
>>> pprint(groupby_list)
[[[0, 0, 'increase', 3, 6, 3],
  [0, 0, 'increase', 10, 6, -4],
  [0, 0, 'increase', 11, 6, -5]],
 [[0, 0, 'increase', 20, 6, -1]],
 [[0, 1, 'increase', 3, 7, 4]],
 [[0, 2, 'low', 6, 2, -4]]]
>>>
```

Comment: This will combine multiple items that fail the bounds check if they have the same first three elements. Otherwise it'd be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby


input_list = [[0, 0, 'increase', 3, 6, 3],
           [0, 0, 'increase', 10, 6, -4],
           [0, 0, 'increase', 11, 6, -5],
           [0, 0, 'increase', 20, 6, -1],
           [0, 1, 'increase', 3, 7, 4],
           [0, 2, 'low', 6, 2, -4]]

s = sorted(input_list, key=lambda k: (k[0], k[1], k[2], abs(k[3] - k[4]) > 5))

all_data = []
for _, g in groupby(s, lambda k: (k[0], k[1], k[2], abs(k[3] - k[4]) > 5)):
    all_data.append(list(g))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(all_data)
```

Prints:

```
[[[0, 0, 'increase', 3, 6, 3],
  [0, 0, 'increase', 10, 6, -4],
  [0, 0, 'increase', 11, 6, -5]],
 [[0, 0, 'increase', 20, 6, -1]],
 [[0, 1, 'increase', 3, 7, 4]],
 [[0, 2, 'low', 6, 2, -4]]]
```

Comment: I think this has the same flaw - assuming I've correctly understood the desired behavior - that @prem_anand's solution does. Test it on `[[0, 0, 'low', 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 'low', 8, 5, 0], [0, 0, 'low', 20, 0, 0], [0, 0, 'low', 30, 0, 0]]` - my understanding is that that should produce three groups, one for the two elements that fit the catchment window and one each for the two values that do not.